# Automatically build OMNeT++ project from command line

Tags: eclipse-cdt, omnet++

I have an OMNeT++ project that builds just fine when I press the "Build" button in IDE:

[image]

However, the build fails if I try the same `make MODE=release all` from a bash terminal:
[image]

I've been trying to figure out why this happens for a long time, but still have no clue. I'm doing experiments that change a variable inside a source file 1000 times, so I cannot manually change the file and click on the button every time. Is there a way to do this automatically?

In case you need to know, my build configurations on the IDE look like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my PATH was searching for compilers in an previous installation of OMNeT++:

```
gabriel@localhost:~$ echo $PATH
/home/gabriel/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/opt/omnetpp-5.7/bin
```

while I the IDE looked for compilers at `/opt/omnetpp-6.0/bin`:
[image]

Setting PATH to the correct version solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some `*.msg` files were built using an older version of `opp_msgtool`.

I suggest in IDE:

1. In `Project` | `Properties` go to `C/C++ Build` | `Behaviour` and for `Build (incremental build)` change `all` to `all V=1` - to see full log of compilation.
2. Clean your project `Project` | `Clean`.
3. Build your project.

Then go to console and in the directory of your project type:

```
make clean
make MODE=release all V=1
```

The results and logs in IDE should be the same as in the console.

Comment: I was indeed building files with an older version of `opp_msgtool` when running from the console because my PATH was pointing to an older version of OMNeT++. Setting it to the new version solved the issue.